# Yet another Python encoding issue

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have trying this code:

```
def process_request(url):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    return urlopen(req).read()

def get_links():
    url = c.first_url
    html = process_request(url)
    details_pages = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.select(".pagelist-bar  a")
    print(links)
    for l in links:
        print(l)
        if l.has_attr('href'):
            href_ = l['href']
            detail = c.base_url + href_
            logging.info("Page with List of persons: %s", detail)
            details_pages.append(detail)
    return details_pages

def person_urls():
    pages = get_links()
    for l in pages:
        print("link: %s", l)
        doc = process_request(l)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
        fichas = soup.select(".ficha")
        print(fichas)
```

In this url:
http://www.guardiacivil.es/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html

And no matter what strategy I use, this line:

```
<a href="/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html?buscar=si&category=abcd&notshown=">
```

is always converted to:

```
<a href="/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html?buscar=si&category=abcd¬shown=">
```

The **&notshown=** becomes **¬shown=**

I have tried some of the suggestions on [THESE POSTS](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=urllib+UnicodeEncodeError%3A+%27ascii%27+codec+can%27t+encode+character&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) with no results so far.

Besides always having the error:

```
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1250, in _send_request
  self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1117, in putrequest
  self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xac' in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try replacing `html.parser` by just `html` in your BeautifulSoup call :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html')
links = soup.select(".pagelist-bar  a")
#Ouptut
for x in links:
    print(x.get('href'))
```

**Output:**

```
/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html?pagina=1&buscar=si&category=&notshown=
/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html?pagina=2&buscar=si&category=&notshown=
/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html?pagina=3&buscar=si&category=&notshown=
/es/colaboracion/buscados/index.html?pagina=4&buscar=si&category=&notshown=
```